# Looping over variable names

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a specific question about looping variable names in WPF.

XAML code looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <Button name="button1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button name="button2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button name="button3" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Button name="button4" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

I wonder if it is possible to loop over the variable names with something as a for loop with a number like:

```
private DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
private CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    /* (*Plus i*): A example as what I want/like to do */
    string Year = String.Format(ci, "{0:yyyy}", Time.addDays(i-1));
    button(*Plus i*).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    button(*Plus i*).Name = Year;
}
```

Is it even possible to add a number to reach a certain variable? 
please help me out, thank you for any response..

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this, there are much better "wpfish" ways to do it. First of all an ItemsControl, a ViewModel with the properties you want to assign; an ItemTemplate containing your items. And finally a list of all the models, representing your item bound to the ItemsControl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to iterate over buttons in that Grid, than your can assign name to the Grid, say *buttonsGrid*. Than you can iterate over it's Children property

```
foreach (var childButton in buttonsGrid.Children.OfType<Button>())
// do smth
```

Comment: This is the solutions I looked for, Thanks mate for your fast respond!

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a variable by name generated in runtime.

---

But you can access control by name generated in runtime:

```
TextBox textbox = grid.FindName("button" + i) as TextBox;
```

Comment: Why cannot? With reflection it might be possible. Anyway, enumerating the grid's logical children should be a more generic solution.

Comment: @Vlad: Honestly I don't know how to and never have seen an access to a method's body via Reflection. I doubt it's possible. Can you give an example?

Comment: I bet you can, but it would be very ugly to do so. Especially if there is a FindName method.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean accessing the method's body (although that might be possible as well), I meant enumerating the Window (UserControl, whatever) class's members by their names and filtering out all that are not buttons. Having a name means that the items is accessible as a member of the enclosing Window/Page/UserControl/...